# Find similarity between rows of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

For Example in one classification problem's dataset we have 50 categories so it will be difficult for model to predict these many classes.
So to avoid this i want to combine target variable's rows which are having similar kind of feature values.

| x1 | x2 | x3 | Y | New Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | val1 | val_u |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | val2 | val_u |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | val3 | val_a |

Here in above example row1 and row2 are similar so their target variable value is replaced with some other name(val_u).

I want to find the similarity between multiple row of a dataset so that classes can be combined(reduced in number)  and their Probability distribution should remain the almost same.

One Approach i can think of is apply clustering but not sure about the probability distribution after clustring..

Answer (score -1):

Something like finding the [euclidian distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between all rows, and grouping the closest ones might help.